# Excel vba to compare two column values of different work book

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match, vba

I prepared a code to compare two column values of different work book and if Result column value is greater than Reference column value then result column value should coloured as yellow. The code is not working properly with all the values. Some values are not getting coloured even though the Result value is greater when comparing with reference value.  Please find my code below
- Code will check weather the A column data(Reference) is present at Result book A column
-If Present copy the corresponding B column data of Referance to F column  of Result
- Compare E(Result Value) and F column, if E column values is greater than F mark it as yellow(E column)

```
Sub ResultComparison()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim y As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Comparison\ReferanceResult.xlsx")
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Comparison\Results.xlsx")

Set wb1sht = wb1.Worksheets("Measurements")
Set wb2sht = wb2.Worksheets("ReferanceMeasurement")

LastRowWb1 = wb1sht.Cells(wb1sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowWb2 = wb2sht.Cells(wb2sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For y = 2 To LastRowWb2
    'Fetching the first value from Referance book   
    findMe = wb2sht.Range("A" & y).Value
    With wb1sht.Range("A2:A" & LastRowWb1)
       Set oFound = .Find(findMe)
        If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
           'If found the Referance book value in Result book.Copying the B column value to adajuscent column F of Result.xlsx
           wb1sht.Range("F" & oFound.Row).Value = wb2sht.Range("B" & y).Value
           ' Comparing the values(E column value to F column value)
           If wb1sht.Range("E" & oFound.Row).Value > wb1sht.Range("F" & oFound.Row).Value Then
               wb1sht.Range("E" & oFound.Row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

**Output of given code:**

[image: Output of given code]

**Reference values before copying to Result.xlsx:**

[image: Reference values before copying to Result.xlsx]

Comment: You wrote "Compare E(Result Value) and F column if E column values is less than F mark it as yellow" but in your code you worte Range("E"...) **>** Range("F"...  ?

Comment: Oops. Its a mistake in my post. Will edit now. Compare E(Result Value) and F column if E column values is greater  than F mark it as yellow. Thank you